# Creating a 3D plane in Python w/ Regression Analysis

Tags: python, 3d, regression

I know very little about coding but I'm trying to perform a regression analysis using two independent variables. I know how to create a 3D scatter plot in Python, and I know how to run a regression analysis in it as well, but I don't know how to put everything together. Let me show what I'm trying to do:
[Regression Analysis Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmE9L.png)
I assembled this using excel. Scatter plot w/ a trend line as well as the equation of the trend line and the R^2 number. I'm currently trying to see if I can create a 3D version (utilizing an addition independent variable) using Python.

I got some help with ChatGPT on getting this started but the results were not what I was hoping for. Here is the code with the output:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
x= *insert my numbers*
y= *insert my numbers*
z= *insert my numbers*
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(np.column_stack((x, y)), z)
coef_x, coef_y = model.coef_
intercept = model.intercept_
x_plane, y_plane = np.meshgrid(np.linspace([min(x), max(x)], 10), np.linspace([min(y), max(y)],    10))
z_plane = coef_x * x_plane + coef_y * y_plane + intercept
ax.plot_surface(x_plane, y_plane, z_plane, alpha=0.5)
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
plt.show()
```

[1st Attempt 3D Plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWDvI.png)

While the scatter plot looks perfect, the plane is not what I wanted. I was hoping for the plane to stretch the entire graph, not just two lines starting from the origin. Is there something missing from this code I have here? Is creating a 3D version of the excel plot I made even possible? Someone please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need a library. You can just code up a standard least-squares analysis. Form

[image]

Partial-differentiate with respect to a, b, c in turn and set equal to 0:

[image]

Arrange as a set of simultaneous linear equations:

[image]

and solve for explicit solutions

[image]

where, e.g.,

[image]

and

[image]

etc.

Sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def planeFit( x, y, z ):
    '''
    Calculate least-squares best fit for z = ax + by + c
    '''
    N = len( x )
    xbar = sum( x ) / N
    ybar = sum( y ) / N
    zbar = sum( z ) / N
    Sxx = sum( x * x ) / N - xbar * xbar
    Syy = sum( y * y ) / N - ybar * ybar
    Sxy = sum( x * y ) / N - xbar * ybar
    Sxz = sum( x * z ) / N - xbar * zbar
    Syz = sum( y * z ) / N - ybar * zbar
    denominator = Sxx * Syy - Sxy ** 2
    a = ( Syy * Sxz - Sxy * Syz ) / denominator
    b = ( Sxx * Syz - Sxy * Sxz ) / denominator
    c = zbar - a * xbar - b * ybar
    return a, b, c


# Enter data
x = np.array( [ 9, 12, 15, 18 ] )
y = np.array( [ 2,  6,  4,  1 ] )
z = 5 * x - 3 * y + 7
z[3] = z[3] - 25         # a little bit of noise


# Fit the plane as z = ax+by+c
a, b, c = planeFit( x, y, z )
fmt = "{:8.3f}  "
print( "Best fit a, b, c = ", ( 3 * fmt ).format( a, b, c ) )


# Check numerical values
zfit = a * x + b * y + c
print( "Values x, y, z, zfit:" )
for i in range( len( x ) ): 
    print( ( 4 * fmt ).format( x[i], y[i], z[i], zfit[i] ) )


# Check plot
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot( projection='3d' )
ax.scatter( x, y, z, color='r' )
x1d = np.linspace( min( x ), max( x ), 5 )
y1d = np.linspace( min( y ), max( y ), 5 )
x2d, y2d = np.meshgrid( x1d, y1d )
zplane = a * x2d + b * y2d + c
ax.plot_surface( x2d, y2d, zplane, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.3 )
ax.set_xlabel( 'X' )
ax.set_ylabel( 'Y' )
ax.set_zlabel( 'Z' )
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I put that code in with my data. I have the scatter plot with a plane now, but the plane doesn't seem to be correct on my end. It is only moving along the y&z axes, nothing in the x. I'm wondering if I still could be missing something. I put in the code exactly how you did, only difference being my data (60 variables for x, y, and z respectively).

Comment: Difficult to comment without seeing your data, @user23523627.